# How to compute the joint probability density function from a joint cumulative density function in Jax?

Tags: python, probability-density, probability-distribution, automatic-differentiation, jax

I have a joint cumulative density function defined in python as a function of a jax array and returning a single value.
Something like:

```py
def cumulative(inputs: array) -> float:
    ...
```

To have the gradient, I know I can just do `grad(cumulative)`, but that is only giving me the first-order partial derivatives of cumulative with respect to the input variables.
Instead, what I would like to do is to compute is this, assuming F is my function and f the joint probability density function:

[image: formula]

The order of the partial derivation doesn't matter.

So, I have several questions:

- how to compute this efficiently in Jax? I assume I cannot just call grad n times
- once the resulting function is computed, will the resulting function have a higher call complexity than the original function (is it increased by O(n), or is it constant, or something else)?
- alternatively, how can I compute a single partial derivative with respect to only one of the variable of the input array, as opposed to the entire array? (And I will just repeat this n times, once per variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX generally treats gradients as being with respect to individual arguments, not elements within arguments. Within this context, one built-in function that is similar to what you want to do (but not exactly the same) is `jax.hessian`, which computes the hessian matrix of second derivatives; for example:

```python
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x):
  return jnp.prod(x ** 2)

x = jnp.arange(1.0, 4.0)
print(jax.hessian(f)(x))
# [[72. 72. 48.]
#  [72. 18. 24.]
#  [48. 24.  8.]]
```

For higher-order derivatives with respect to individual elements of the array, I think you'll have to manually nest the gradients. You could do so with a helper function that looks something like this:

```python
def grad_all(f):
  def gradfun(x):
    args = tuple(x)
    f_args = lambda *args: f(jnp.array(args))
    for i in range(len(args)):
      f_args = jax.grad(f_args, argnums=i)
    return f_args(*args)
  return gradfun

print(grad_all(f)(x))
# 48.0
```

Comment: Your function seems sound and run, but I'm getting negative values which I believe shouldn't be possible. Could it be that your function is correct but that jax somehow manages to get negative values where it shouldn't?

Comment: Depending on the inputs, floating point rounding errors could cause JAX to produce negative values when none would be expected.

Comment: I see, is there a simple way to prevent this? Can I just take clip the value of the gradient at each step of the loop for instance?

Comment: Maybe? Hard to say without more information. But taking gradients of clipped functions can run into other issues with boundary conditions.